# Accessing the data from localstorage from another route with vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuex, vue-router

i am getting the data from a config panel route setting it to the localstorage with vuex , storeJS:

```
     const state = {
      message: [],
      // console.log(message);
      sec: 0,
      // other state
    };
    const getters = {
      message: (state) => {
        // console.log(this.state.message);
    
        return state.message;
      },
    
      sec: (state) => {
        return state.sec;
      },
      // other getters
    };
    
    const actions = {
      setMessage: ({ commit, state }, inputs) => {
        commit(
          'SET_MESSAGE',
          inputs.map((input) => input.message)
        );
    
        return state.message;
      },

  setSec: ({ commit, state }, newSecVal) => {
    commit('SET_TIMEOUT', newSecVal);
    return state.sec;
  },
  // other actions
};
const mutations = {
  SET_MESSAGE: (state, newValue) => {
    state.message = newValue;
    localStorage.setItem('message', JSON.stringify(newValue));  ----->this
  },
  SET_TIMEOUT: (state, newSecVal) => {
    state.sec = newSecVal;
    localStorage.setItem('sec', JSON.stringify(newSecVal));  --->this
  },
  // other mutations
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

Now i am having a home route where i want to display this ,how can i access that?

I am getting the data (not the localstorage but the regular state data)   with Mapgetters  and i am using it like that:

```
computed: {
   

    ...mapGetters({
      message: "message",
      sec: "sec"
    }),
```

how can i tell him that if there is nothing (when a page reloads ) to automaticcally get the data from localstorage.
This is my MOunted

```
mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("SET_MESSAGE");
    this.$store.dispatch("SET_SEC");
 
    
  },
```

Comment: In mutation, you can put it like state.message || localStorage.getItem('message')

Comment: where exactly you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you use this package to keep your state and local storage in sync [vuex-persistedstate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate).

Alternatively, you can set your state like this.

```
const state = {
  message: localStorage.getItem('message') || [],
  // console.log(message);
  sec: localStorage.getItem('sec') || '',
  // other state
};
```